# Neo4J + Spring If relation is empty it errors

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have 2 Nodes:

```
@Node
class Person
{
    String name;
    @Relationship(type = "WORKED_AT", direction = INCOMING)
    List<Job> jobs;
}

@Node
class Job
{
    String name;
}
```

When I call repository of Person method findAll() it throws error when Person don't have any existing relationship. When I remove Relationship part it works normally.

How do i make it work (it is not mandatory that every Person has a job).

PS: it is not full code - so i did not include here IDs, default repository etc. in those is not any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a version issue, my neo4j DB version was 4.1.* when I updated to 4.3.* everything was fixed.